# php oop and pdo notworking in web hosting

Tags: php, oop

my init.php
Here's the code of the connect in hosting but not working

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'db' => 'db'
),
'remember' => array(
    'cookie_name' => 'hash',
    'cookie_expiry' => 604800
),
'sessions' => array(
    'session_name' => 'user',
    'token_name' => 'token'
));?>
```

and my db.php
Here's the code of the connect in hosting but not working
and connect database web hosting,
just show blank page in my hosting 
plz help me.

```
<?php

 class DB {
private static $_instance = null;
private $_pdo,
        $_query,
        $_error = false,
        $_results,
        $_count = 0,
        $_last_insert_id ;

private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password') );
        $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,TRUE);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}
```

Comment: A blank page is most likely a "500 server error", turn on error messages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: thanks , right now show 
500 Internal Server Error
how to fix it ?

Comment: Did you turn on error messages?

Comment: yes i did find the error     Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: usually the root user dis activated on a shared hostings. Try to create a different user with the password. The code itself looks good

Comment: thanks  now working ...